Help identify part with marking code |ACG and VE
I have two similar 5-pin sots, one with marking |ACG and another one VE. They're probably tvs diodes but I can't be sure. I need part number for both of this.
I have searched through various smd manuals but couldn't find the exact match. Also please suggest an efficient way to search for these parts that'll actually work.


Since the designator is IC rather than D then they could be anything. And quite unlikely TVS given the SOT23-5.

IC28 is most likely an 74LVC1G08GW AND Gate from nexperia, LCSC has a picture:

The way I found it: the marking style looked like nexperia so I searched for "VE marking nexperia SOT23-5" using duckduckgo and it was the 4th result.
Quik lookup on lcsc for a real picture of the IC and it looked similar enough.

The second one could be a SN74AHC1G04DCKR, see also TI search.
